# Odoo - Subtract 2 "time" fields in python

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

```
for emp in employee:
  contract_id = contract_pool.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id','=',emp.employee_id.id)], context=context)
     for contract in contract_pool.browse(cr, uid, contract_id, context=context):
        for attendance in contract.working_hours.attendance_ids:
          if day == attendance.dayofweek:
             planned_time_in = attendance.hour_from
             planned_time_out = attendance.hour_to
             planned_wrkng_hrs = planned_time_out - planned_time_in
             print planned_wrkng_hrs
  actual_time_in = emp.time_in
  actual_time_out = emp.time_out
  actual_wrkd_hrs = actual_time_out - actual_time_in
  print actual_wrkd_hrs
  hrs_short = planned_wrkng_hrs - actual_wrkd_hrs
  print hrs_short
```

This gives me output as:
9.00
8.57
0.43
How can I get:
9:00
8:57
00:03
Float values are getting subtracted here instead of time.

Comment: convert the time to second and then do the operations, once you get the result in second divide it by 60 for min and 3600 for hour

Answer (score 0):

assuming the format of the time values is like in your example, you can convert it to minutes-since-midnight by doing something like

```
time_in_mins = int(original_time) * 60 + (original_time - int(original(time)) * 100
```

then do all your calculations using the new "normalized" values, and later convert it back to your preferred format for display or storage.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you ^^:

```py
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime, date
import math
# on thing hour part cannot be more that 23 and 
first_time = 23.5
secend_time = 23.0

# convert float to hour and minute
f_hour, f_time = int(math.floor(first_time)), int(round((first_time % 1) * 60))
s_hour, s_time = int(math.floor(secend_time)), int(round((secend_time % 1) * 60))
# create datetime object to perform substraction
duration = datetime.combine(date.min,time(f_hour,f_time))- datetime.combine(date.min,time(s_hour,s_time))
print "total minute between this two time is %s minutes " % (duration.total_seconds() / 60)
```

Result:

```
total minute between this two time is 30.0 minutes
```

Comment: What is date.min here?

Comment: it's jut a min date 0001-01-01 to create a date with time so the result is 0001-01-01 23:30:00  0001-01-01 23:00:00 didn't work for you ?